# Unobserved component model (UCM) error message in R (RUCM Package)

Tags: r, time-series

I have daily data from past 2 year. I have monthly seasonality. So i want to include 11 dummy variables.

```
dat<-read.csv("data.csv")
val.ts <- ts(dat$Actual,start=c(2014,1,1),freq=12)
```

when i try to run the command

```
mymod <- ucm(val.ts~dat[,2:12],cycle = TRUE,cycle.period = 12)
```

I get error message

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , as.character(dep.var)) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Comment: According to help page (always a good idea to read the help page), `ucm` function takes a **formula** as input (`ucm(formula, data, ...)`). This is not your case.

Comment: Thanks i followed your instruction and used the formula argument and again i get a new error message. Post is updated

Comment: You should follow the help page.

Comment: I did check the help page and this is how i realized that i missed using tilted sign ~ for formula

Comment: But `val.ts~dat[,2:12]` is an incorrect construction for a formula. Please read some documentation
.

Comment: There is no clear explanation on the help page of this function about how to construct a formula argument. In fact this technique is about passing other predictors along with the time series as dependent variable. The help page of the function DOES NOT have any specification about how to pass independent variable and the example data set 'Nile' does not have an independent variable either! That leaves me no where. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if the following works for you.

```
library(rucm)

dat <- read.csv("data.csv")
fo <- as.formula(paste("Actual ~ ", paste(names(dat)[2:13], collapse= "+")))
mymod <- ucm(fo, data = dat, cycle = TRUE, cycle.period = 12)
```

Here is a test with dummy data:

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(Nile, matrix(rnorm(1200), 100, 12)))
colnames(dat) <- c("Actual", paste0("V", 1:12))
fo <- as.formula(paste("Actual ~ ", paste(names(dat)[2:13], collapse= "+")))
mymod <- ucm(fo, data = dat, cycle = TRUE, cycle.period = 12)

mymod
# Call:
# ucm(formula = fo, data = dat, cycle = TRUE, cycle.period = 12)

# Parameter estimates:
#     Estimate Approx.StdErr   t.val p.value  
# V1   -8.1606       15.4735 -0.5274 0.59925  
# V2    4.6288       14.1291  0.3276 0.74399  
# V3    7.7008       14.7144  0.5234 0.60205  
# V4  -15.8045       14.0253 -1.1269 0.26287  
# V5  -11.5938       14.4435 -0.8027 0.42431  
# V6  -22.4537       14.9448 -1.5024 0.13656  
# V7   -2.6873       13.2951 -0.2021 0.84028  
# V8  -26.5699       14.1251 -1.8810 0.06327 .
# V9   12.5518       12.9471  0.9695 0.33497  
# V10  13.3437       13.8729  0.9619 0.33876  
# V11 -12.0410       13.2171 -0.9110 0.36477  
# V12   2.8637       13.8277  0.2071 0.83641  
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

# Estimated variance:
# Irregular_Variance     Level_Variance     Cycle_Variance 
#         14722.8809           545.6452             7.0148
```